# Generating a Controller (Getting Started with Rails, Chapter 6.4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am following the [Getting Started with Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html) and have made it up to 6.4 when it prompts this code:

```
$ rails generate controller Comments
```

My terminal puts this out:

```
johns-MacBook-Pro:blog john$ rails g controller Comments
/Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:10:in `rescue in execute_if_updated': Rails::Application::RoutesReloader#execute_if_updated delegated to updater.execute_if_updated, but updater is nil: #<Rails::Application::RoutesReloader:0x007faa4156ec60 @paths=["/Users/john/rails/blog/config/routes.rb"], @route_sets=[#<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007faa41933a30>]> (RuntimeError)
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:6:in `execute_if_updated'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:215:in `initialize!'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/john/rails/blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:189:in `require_environment!'
    from /Users/john/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:45:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
johns-MacBook-Pro:blog john$
```

I am new to coding and have no idea where to start looking for fix for this.

Here is routes.rb:

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do     
  resources :posts

  root to: "welcome#index"
end

resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

Comment: looks like an error in your routes.rb file.  can you post that as well? /Users/john/rails/blog/config/routes.rb

Comment: I should've said, edit your original post and add it there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO and the wonderful world of Ruby on Rails :D

looks like you need to move

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments
end
```

into the routes.draw block

e.g./

```
Blog::Application.routes.draw do     
  resources :posts

  root to: "welcome#index"

  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Comment: np.  I remember the early days of SO & RoR, stick with it if you can...:D